# Can't optimize footer for emails. Problem with Outlook for Dark mode users

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, darkmode

I can't seem to optimize how my email footers look like in Outlook for Dark mode users.

Here are the Dark vs Light versions

[Light Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ds96N.png)

[Dark Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2FWb.png)

Here's the code of the footer;

```
<td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 20px; background-color: #000; mso-color-alt: auto; font-size: 15px;" width="100%" valign="top" height="100%" bgcolor="#000" align="center"> 
    <table role="presentation" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse!important;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center"> 
        <tbody>
```

Here's the code of one of the logos;

```
<tr> 
    <td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="60" align="center">
                    <a style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; display: block;" href="#" target="_blank" _label="Footer: facebook" data-nl-type="externalLink" data-nl-lnkep-perso-attr-href="https://www.facebook.com/"> <img src="http://.png" alt="facebook logo" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: 0px; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: 33px;" width="33" /></a>
    </td>
```

I also tried:

```
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
<meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">

<style>
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark ) {
  .footer { background-color: #000000 !important; }
  p { color: #ffffff !important; }
}
</style>
```

But doesn't seem to work.

Comment: By "Outlook", do you mean Outlook webmail (Outlook.com), or Outlook desktop on Windows? Or other?

Comment: Outlook desktop for Windows but i think the problem applies to all Outlook versions.

Comment: Don't have time to write this up right now, but check out this working solution - using VML background image (OL doesn't accept normal background images) to keep the colour the same, because OL dark mode doesn't change image colours: https://codepen.io/LorinCerina/pen/XWVaeoN?editors=1000